# Abstract Data Type

Tags: data-structures, arrays, sets, lists, abstract-data-types

I have been studying data structures. In that I have come across topics like Array being defined as Power set of cross product of set of objects and set of natural number and list being defined as sequence of objects. I wanted to read more about these things but I haven't been able to find any reference. Can anyone help me?